# Possible to not persist a Apache Kafka topic to disk

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a specific use-case where I am not allowed to persist a certain kind
of events. The events can be kept in memory, but not written to the disk.

Is this even possible with Kafka? Ideally I am looking for a per topic
configuration to disable the writing to disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible. On the Kafka mailing list I got this suggestion:

> you could configure the topic to reside on a tmp-fs mount (i.e., in
>   memory filesystem with no disk backing).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can prevent Kafka from writing something to disk since changing that would involve changing its core architecture. One suggestion would be to create a topic for these special events that has a very short retention time (say a few minutes).